# Add an image into LaTeX IEEE Journal template, Thanks section

Tags: templates, journal

I am wondering how is it possible to add an image into thanks section of IEEE journal template. I would be grateful if anyone can help me.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\ifCLASSINFOpdf
\else
\fi
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\hyphenation{op-tical net-works semi-conduc-tor}
\begin{document}
\title{Paper Title}
\author{FisrtName~LastName,~\IEEEmembership{Member,~IEEE,}
\thanks{Text
\includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{Picture.jpg}
}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: @campa Thanks, I have tried that, but It was not shown, I think the reason is the place of `\thanks{}` which is located within `\author{}` command.

Comment: Well, then as samcarter said you must provide a MWE. Otherwise no one can know what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Roozbeh Thanks for adding some code. Can you please make a compilable document that actually shows the thanks section?

Comment: Uhm, the argument of `\thanks` is basically a footnote. `\protect\includegraphics` might do the trick.